# Understanding the regress function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I'm having trouble understanding how regress works in Matlab.

Say I have 2 arrays (X and Y), each having the same size (let's say they're each 1x10). From what I understand, the regress function should help me find the relationship between X and Y (I want to draw a best fit line through the plotted data), and then give me the slope. When I tried this in Matlab, I got an error saying that the 2 variables have a different number of rows....but they don't, do they?

I would just really appreciate it if anyone could help me understand how the function and its parameters work, just to get me going at a basic level.

Here's some code as an example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; %defining the arrays, they are linearly related
X=[x ones(size(x,1),1)]; %adding the (necessary?) column of ones
regress(y,X) % using the regress function for a relationship
```

I get this error:

```
??? Error using ==> regress at 64
The number of rows in Y must equal the number of rows in X.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're confusing rows with columns somehow (Matlab uses [column-major ordering](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)). If you print out your two inputs, `y` and `X`, you'll see immediately that they're row vectors of different lengths. Read the help/documentation for [`regress`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) carefully – the first input must be an N-by-1 column vector. And the second an N-by-p matrix. Therefore something like this could work:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
X = [x; ones(1,length(x))];
b = regress(y.',X.')
```

Answer (score 1):

`regress` is for multiple linear regression. You just want to find relation between `X` and `Y`. For that `polyfit` command should be enough. I think the column of ones is necessary only when you want to calculate statistics.

From MATLAB documentation:

> regress is for multiple linear regression. You just want to find relation between *X* and *Y*. For that *polyfit* command should be enough. I think the column of ones is necessary only when you want to calculate statistics.

You will use `regress` when you want to find out how `Z` behaves with respect to `X` and `Y`. In short, `Z=f(X,Y)`. In this case, you will plug `Z` as a `nx1` vector (first argument in `regress` command). Then you form another matrix, say `D=[X Y]`. This is a `nx2` vector. This will be the second argument for the `regress` command.

Now read this from MATLAB docs again, see if it makes sense:

> *b = regress(y,X)* returns a p-by-1 vector b of coefficient estimates for a multilinear regression of the responses in y on the predictors in X. X is an n-by-p matrix of p predictors at each of n observations. y is an n-by-1 vector of observed responses.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between multiple linear regression and normal regression ? I could not understand the difference between the commands fitlm and regress in matlab.

Comment: Regarding `fitlm` vs. `regress`, both are linear regressors. I think `fitlm` is better organized and you can plot, calculate metrics etc. using the methods in `fitlm`. You can't do so many things in `regress`. However, I am not sure. I think you meant "multivariate normal regression", for that read `mvregress` of MATALB and compare that with `regress`. You should get the difference.